# joomla build custom module form field after param change value

Tags: joomla, module, content-management-system

I searched all over the net but I can't find the asnwer so I hope that someone can help me.
I want to develop a joomla module which generate a menu. I want to build a form parameters field of the module which allows the user to select the number of entry in the menu and, after this choice, it generates as many param labels as the user choosed.
I made a simple example to clarify my problem:

```
<!-- This is the first parameter where user choose the number of entry-->
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
......
</select>
<!-- Suppose that user selects 5, so i need to generate 5 input field -->

<input>.....</input>
<input>.....</input>
<input>.....</input>
<input>.....</input>
<input>.....</input>
```